# How to disable button in vuejs

Tags: laravel, vue.js

I want to make the button disabled during the form filling
when all the inputs are filled the button will be enabled using vuejs and on laravel framework

I tried achive that by simply making the button disabled in the

```
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-info" disabled>Next</button>
```

but i didn't know how to do it in vuejs

Answer (score 79, accepted):

Just bind the `disabled` attribute to a boolean value like

```
<button :disabled='isDisabled'>Send Form</button>
```

as in [this example](https://jsfiddle.net/willywg/2g7m5qy5/)

Answer (score 13):

You can use a **computed property** to make the button enable / disable. Each time the condition changes inside the computed property, the button disable or enable will be rendered. The condition should be a boolean.

```html
<template>
  ...
  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-info" :disabled="isDisabled">Next</button>
  ...
</template>

<script>
  export default {
    computed: {
      isDisabled() {
        // you can  check your form is filled or not here.
        return yourCondition == true
      },
    },
  }
</script>
```

Answer (score 2):

https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/syntax.html#Attributes

```
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-info" :disabled="validated">Next</button>
```

Bind the `disabled` attribute to a boolean value, once validated, or in your case all inputs are filled return `true`

Answer (score 2):

We disable the element using property `disabled` and value is boolean which we can set using computation or directly into the property value. Like:

```
<button class="btn" :disabled="computedCondition">Next</button>

   computed: {
    computedCondition() { 
     return true or false;
    }
   }
```

we just use disabled and can use computed if we need flexible outcome which is dependent on other data.

Hope this helps.
Have a good day.

Answer (score 1):

This code work for me.

Button:-

```
  <button
                id="myBtn"
                @click="pay()"
                class="btn btn-primary"
                :disabled="!isComplete"
              >
                Pay ${{ this.amount }}
              </button>
```

In computed (I check if my properties are empty or not if all are filled, I returned **TRUE** that results in **ENABLE** button )

```
  isComplete () {
      return (
        this.user_name != '' &&
        this.email != '' &&
        this.phone != '' &&
        this.address != ''
      )
    }
```

And Finally, use the following CSS

```
#myBtn:disabled {
  cursor: not-allowed;
  opacity: 0.8;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

if you don't want to use a computed property, you can directly write your condition in the html attribute "disabled" with " v-bind " or just " : ".

```
<button class="btn btn-primary" @click="add(item)" v-bind:disabled="item.amount >= 3"> 
   Add 
</button>
```